# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API: malformed JObject: diagnose and write to log file

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API with a `POST` method that accepts a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` as a `[FromBody]` parameter. In my code, I log the raw `jobject.tostring()` to a log file.

I'm having trouble diagnosing a "malformed JObject" error, and writing to the log file. How do I accomplish my task?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]  JObject transactionData)
{        
    var logWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\Logs\somefilename.txt", true);

    try
    {
        logWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + ": " + transactionData.ToString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + ": " + e.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally 
    {
        logWriter.Close();
        logWriter.Dispose();
        logWriter = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you set a breakpoint at `JObject transactionData` ? Could you get the data ? Below answer is based that I can get the data .

Answer (score 0):

> How do I accomplish my task?

Below is what I do based your code,then I can get a text, you can refer to it, hope it can help.

1.Add the Nuget package :

```
Newtonsoft.Json
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

2.Add the code in the ConfigureServices method in the Startup class  look like:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

3.Change (`D:\Logs\somefilename.txt` :`\` into `/` )

```
var logWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\Logs\somefilename.txt", true);
```

into:

```
 var logWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:/Logs/somefilename.txt", true);
```

4. result:

[image]